# How to configure X11 to find a font as requested by a proprietary binary

Tags: fonts

Starting a proprietary binary I get the following error message:

```
FATAL ERROR from X-windows: font not found: -*-*helvetica-bold-r-normal-*-11-*-*-*-*-*-*-*
```

I'm not quite experienced in handling with fonts, but as far as I understand that string `-*-*helvetica-bold-r-normal-*-11-*-*-*-*-*-*-*` should match a helvetica font, bold, in size 11, which should be quite a normal font.

After googling I tried the following things without result:

```
$ sudo xlsfonts -fn -*-*helvetica-bold-r-normal-*-11-*-*-*-*-*-*-*
xlsfonts: pattern "-*-*helvetica-bold-r-normal-*-11-*-*-*-*-*-*-*" unmatched
# in case the `*` is a problem:
$ sudo xlsfonts -fn -*-helvetica-bold-r-normal-*-11-*-*-*-*-*-*-*
xlsfonts: pattern "-*-helvetica-bold-r-normal-*-11-*-*-*-*-*-*-*" unmatched
```

also

```
$ sudo mkfontdir
$ sudo xset fp rehash
```

didn't help.

How can I find the problem? And how to solve it?

Comment: What is the file type of the font files you have?

Comment: Good question, 6+ years later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I couldn't find a better solution then changing the strings in a `fonts.dir` file to match the strings.

Assuming that the normal Courier font should be at least readable if used incorrectly, I copied all the files from the vanilla `Type1` folder into a local font folder and also the lines from the `Type1/fonts.dir` which contained the name `courier`. Then I added at the end of the names string just `helvetica` and rehashed the font cache. Then the program could start without an error.

```
$ cp /usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1/c0* ~/fonthack/
$ cp /usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1/fonts.dir ~/fonthack/
$ vim ~/fonthack/fonts.dir
# editing the lines. e.g.:
# from: c0419bt_.pfb -bitstream-courier 10 pitch-medium-r-normal-0-0-0-0-m-0-adobe-standard
# to: c0419bt_.pfb -bitstream-courier 10 pitchhelvetica-medium-r-normal-0-0-0-0-m-0-adobe-standard
# removed all lines without ``courier'' in their names
$ xset fp rehash
$ ~/the_tool_i_want_to_use
```

Answer (score 2):

Is it even installed?

```
fc-list | grep Helvetica
```

If not find the font on the web and create a `.font` directory in your user's home dir.

[Helvetica® font family](http://www.linotype.com/526/helvetica-family.html) or find a Macintosh.

Comment: Your command doesn't list anything, but if i search for `helvetica` in Synaptic it says, that it's installed with the package `ttf-freefont`.

Comment: Not the same. A set of free high-quality TrueType fonts covering the UCS character set. These fonts are similar to the (in)famous Helvetica, Times and Courier fonts.

Comment: And how do I get these (in)famous fonts? (I can find Courier in fc-list, but not the others)

Comment: I added a link. Their not free.

Comment: Yeah, I see. There are fonts.dir files which link existing files to such a searchable string. I will just copy/paste one to have helvetica in it's name, I think.